How do I solve "Required @OA\PathItem() not found error" for Swagger PHP?
I've installed darkaonline/l5-swagger on my Laravel 11 project, unlike most tutorials, I'm placing my swagger documentation on the routes an not above Controller methods (keeps Controller files lean).
When I run php artisan l5-swagger:generate , I get the following error:
Required @OA\PathItem() not found

My routes look something like this:
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *   path="/blogs",
 *   summary="List blogs.",
 *   tags={"blogs"},
 *   
 *   @OA\Response(response=200, description="OK"),
 *   @OA\Response(response=401, description="Unauthorized"),
 *   @OA\Response(response=404, description="Not Found")
 * )
 */
Route::get('/blogs', [BlogController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('blogs.get');

As for what I've tried, I assumed it would be because the l5-swagger.php config file has the following annotations path:
return [
    'default' => 'default',
    'documentations' => [
        'default' => [
                /*
                 * Absolute paths to directory containing the swagger annotations are stored.
                 */
                'annotations' => [
                    base_path('app'),
                ],

           
        ],
    ],
];

So I changed the annotations path to base_path('routes'), But got the same error. I even went as far as using the full api.php file path, like so base_path('routes/api.php'), but I still get the same error.
Everything I find on the issue says I'm missing the path= in my annotation, but as you can see, it's all there.
